# Modal Bootstrap showing in all windows thats same email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Hi i dont know how i should do this. I made showing users in panel admin and its working correct even showing roles on button. Next step what i want to do is click and showing modal bootstrap and here i got problem i dont know how i can pass $user->email to title   when i do this:

```html
<form action="{{route('change')}}" method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal"> 
        {{ csrf_field() }} 
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" name="{{$user->email}}">

    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

                <h4 class="modal-title">Zmiana roli użytkownika o adresie E-mail:</br>
                  <b>{{$user->email}}</b>
                </h4>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

                <p>Wybierz rolę dla użytkownika</p> 
           
           
   <select name="{{$user->email}}">
    <option name="role_user">User</option>
    <option name="role_moderator">Moderator</option>
    <option name="role_admin">Admin</option>
   </select>
   
     
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Zamknij</button>
            <input  name="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Zmień rolę"></input>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

[image]

I have somethink like on screen and i want make change role in this modal. 
In title modal is showing adress email but its showing only last in tables.
So maybe i must name this windows like {{$user->email}} becouse change roles i want base on email becouse its uniqe in database. I made change roles on checkbox but i trying do this better with nice view. I want do somethink like that admin show all user and button near them and he can click button and got info user->email and select. This select showing user role and admin can change and save it. And its showing in all user window last row from table user i mean i got last user admin with role admin so its showing in all window admin details.

**Update 1:**
I do like that:

```
<td><button class="btn btn-info wielkoscPrzycisku" name="{{$user->email}}" id="{{$user->email}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#myModal" value="" data-user-email="{{$user->email}}">{{$roles->name}}</button></td>
```

Its button from i want get data.
Next jquery:

```js
jQuery('#open-modal-button').click(function () {
            user_email = jQuery(this).data('user-email');
            jQuery('modal-title-email').html(user_email);
            
        });
```

Next span button:

```html
<span id="modal-title-email"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what the rest of your code says, so I'm kind of winging it, but what you could do is use jQuery and html data attributes on your table row and when looping through your user array you populate that and have something to grab easily with jquery.

```html
     
     
     <h4 class="modal-title">Zmiana roli użytkownika o adresie E-mail:</br>
        <span id="modal-title-email"></span>
     </h4>
     
     <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td><button data-user-name="John">Admin</button></td>
     </tr>
     
     <script>
        jQuery('#open-modal-button').click(function () {
            username = jQuery(this).data('user-name');
            jQuery('#modal-title-email').html(username);
        });
     </script>
```

When clicking the button that opens the modal you grab the data from the data attribute and then use jQuery html function to add it to your modal title.

Comment: i edit my post i think i do like u write but its not working

Comment: this first loop after the @section('content') is working that i got earlier

Comment: I just updated my post. You'll want to do a span tag at the end of your modal-title h4 and that's what you'll want to fill with jQuery. In my original suggestion, I didn't have this part of your code so I was only assuming what you were using. Give that a shot and let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I update my post like u write maybe i do somethink wrong with button, when i do <button data-user-name="John">Admin</button></td>  like u modal windows was stoping render

Comment: ok its almost work;p but only working on first element its showing mail and when i check console log result is only 1 mail

Comment: oh yes, you have multiple buttons, do you have multiple modals as well? If that's the case you need to use classes and not ids. For example: "#open-modal-button" needs to become ".open-modal-button", but also you need a way to distinguish each one from one another. Does that make since? Can you post all the code on the page?

Comment: i fix it  i spend many hours but now its working thx for help